# Let $V$ be an inner product space and $T\colon V\to V$ a linear operator. Prove that $R(T^{*})^{\bot}=N(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, inner-products

> Let $V$ be an inner product space, and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$.
>   Prove that $R(T^{*})^{\bot}=N(T)$.

I would like to understand the following proof:

> We prove that $ N(T^*) \subset N(T)^{\bot}$. Let $x \in N(T^{*})$, need to prove for all $y \in R(T), \langle x,y \rangle=0$. Let $y \in R(T)$, $y=T(z)$ for some $z \in V$. Then $$\langle x,y \rangle= \langle x,T(z) \rangle= \underbrace{\langle T^{*}(x)}_{0},z \rangle,$$ 
>   so $x \in R(T)^{\bot}$, hence $N(T^{*} \subset R(T)^{\bot}$.
>
> Then we prove the other direction. Let $x \in R(T)^{\bot}$, want to show $T^{*}(x)=0$. We have
>   $$|| T^{*}(x)||^2=\langle  T^{*}(x), T^{*}(x) \rangle=\langle \underbrace{x}_{\in R(T)^{\bot}},\underbrace{T( T^{*}(x))}_{\in R(T)} \rangle,$$
>   so $T^{*}(x)=0$, hence $R(T)^{\bot}=N(T^{*})$.

I am lost in this whole proof. Can someone explain what's going on, why are they attempting to show those things? Much appreciated.

Comment: Which step(s) are you having difficulty with?

Comment: To define $T^{*}$, $T$ has to bounded also.

Comment: begining Let $x \in N(T^{*})$, need to prove for all $y \in R(T), \langle x,y \rangle=0$. I am not sure how to handle

Comment: If you want to prove something for all $y \in R(T)$ you write $y$ as $Tz$ for some $z$. Then apply definition of $T^{*}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I too found the "proof" given in the text of the question obscure and confusing, so much so that I can't really say more; hence my own work is presented below; it is not difficult.

To avoid technical difficulties I assume $T$ is a bounded operator on $V$.

These things being said, let

$x \in N(T); \tag 1$

then

$Tx = 0, \tag 2$

whence

$\forall y \in V, \: \langle y, Tx \rangle = 0; \tag 3$

thus

$\forall y \in V, \; \langle T^\dagger y,  x \rangle = 0, \tag 4$

that is,

$x \in R(T^\dagger)^\bot, \tag 5$

and thus

$N(T) \subset R(T^\dagger)^\bot; \tag 6$

also, in the event that (5) binds, we have

$\forall y \in V, \; \langle T^\dagger y, x \rangle = 0, \tag 7$

or

$\forall y \in V, \; \langle y, Tx \rangle = 0, \tag 8$

which immediately yields

$Tx = 0 \Longrightarrow x \in N(T), \tag 9$

and hence

$R(T^\dagger)^\bot \subset N(T); \tag{10}$

finally, (6) and (10) together imply

$R(T^\dagger)^\bot = N(T), \tag{11}$

$OE\Delta$.